# How to open kubernetes dashboard on azure cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have installed the kubernetes cluster on azure using the link "https://koukia.ca/running-windows-containers-on-kubernetes-cluster-on-azure-container-service-99e8de0d9cf4".But Im not able to access the dashboard on the "http://127.0.0.1/ui".Can you please explain me about this error? Am i missing anything ?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Comment: where the error? can you share it?

Comment: The documentation you're following is really old. You should be using the new `aks` cli tools which greatly simplify interacting with kubernetes

Comment: lol, how would az aks help with acs cluster? @JesseCarter also acs is not outdated one bit.

Comment: huh? dashboard doesnt have a service

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-ui) to browse the k8s UI in Azure.

After you run this command `az acs kubernetes browse -g [Resource Group] -n [Container service instance name]`, this should open a web browser configured to talk to a secure proxy connecting your local machine to the Kubernetes web UI.

That showed a blank page, like this:

[image]

There are something wrong with the redirected, it should redirected to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/
```

Please note that trailing /.

Also you can use `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/` to access it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help?